Highlight substring in Arabic text and ignore diacritics
Let's say there are Arabic strings in javascript:
const resultText = 'اَلْيَوْمُ جَمِيلٌ وَالشَّمْسُ';
const searchText = 'والشم';

The searchText variable is dynamic and might have a different value on runtime. So we need to write a regex that will replace the searchText in the resultText, but the problem is that along with having to write a regex with dynamic variable, also want to ignore certain characters when matching, and those characters to ignore are the diacritics in Arabic. So the end result would be after replacing the string as follows:
"اَلْيَوْمُ جَمِيلٌ <span class="highlighted">وَالشَّم</span>سُ"

so basically want to wrap the searchText word with HTML span tag, but alongside want to ignore diacritics in order have a match for replacing, because the searchText will be without diacritics and the resultText will be with diacritics, if we first remove all the diacritics in resultText, then we would easily have match, but want to keep the diacritics in resultText and still match successfully so in order to do that will need to ignore the diacritics when matching searchText inside it.
So far we have achieved to wrap the matched word in HTML but ignoring the diacritics is remaining:
const searchText = 'والشم';

const resultText = 'اَلْيَوْمُ جَمِيلٌ وَالشَّمْسُ';

const regex1 = new RegExp(this.searchText, 'gi');

const finalText = result.replace(regex1, '<span class="highlighted">$&</span>');

For a hint - the below regex is used to clear all the diacritics from a string:
'وَالشَّمْسُ'.normalize('NFD').replace(/([^\u0621-\u063A\u0641-\u064A\u0660-\u0669a-zA-Z 0-9])/g, '');

So all the diacritics characters are in the above regex pattern, so how can we use the above regex pattern or modify it to use it in the text replacing regex along with the dynamic variable, as described above.

You can do something like searchText.replace(/\B/g,'\.?') (demo)

const resultString = 'اَلْيَوْمُ جَمِيلٌ وَالشَّمْسُ';
const searchText = 'والشم';
let's say we have the above Arabic text, we want to do the same with the above variables. below is a regex which actually replaces all the diacritics in Arabic text with empty string and thus clears all the diacritics:
'وَالشَّمْسُ'.normalize('NFD').replace(/([^\u0621-\u063A\u0641-\u064A\u0660-\u0669a-zA-Z 0-9])/g, '');
so how can we use the above regex pattern so that we can ignore all the diacritics and wrap the searchText with HTML tags in arabic since it is a substring from resultString.

@bobblebubble the expected output would be:
"اَلْيَوْمُ جَمِيلٌ <span class="highlighted">وَالشَّم</span>سُ"

Consider to edit your question or asking a new question and provide the exact requirements (arabic text, characters to ignore) along with input, expected output.

@bobblebubble the question is edited now.

There is a very similar question already, I hope that solves it!

@bobblebubble the attached demo is not working against the following:
const searchText = 'قل اعوذ';
const resultText = 'قُلْ أَعُوذُ بِرَبِّ النَّاسِ';

Your sample not only contains diacritic-marks but also letters like e.g. أ (alef with hamza above) which is different character to ا. Your normalize('NFD') will do what it's supposed to, but to match both, I guess you would need to build a regex map for all that could occur and replace them to e.g. [أا...], addionally within \p{M}* like in the linked answer. I can't help further, maybe someone else. An idea to remove and repost? However good luck!

I found this answer which contains a list of arabic characters and found that the characters that need mapping to one instance are probably [اأإآ], [ؤئ], is that right?

JS demo

I had some quiet time and tried to fiddle something together, hope that helps! Further I tried to improve the title of your question to make it found better, so you might get other options, please check and edit if not appropriate. Have a nice Sunday.

Besides diacritics marks in this one of your samples (comment) there are even characters without such marks that have variations. ا (alef) is a different character to  أ (alef with hamza above).
For matching either you will need to identify all such characters that can occur and replace each occurance in your searchText with a character class, for example replace أ with [اأإآ].
To get started, I would do something like this (experimental, no experience with arabic text).


// highlight arabic substring in text
function highlightArabic (search, text, verbose=false)
{
  // check input for at least one letter or digit
  if(!/[\p{L}\p{N}]/u.test(search) || !/[\p{L}\p{N}]/u.test(text)) {
    return text;
  } 
  
  // 1. normalize and remove special characters
  search = search.normalize('NFD').replace(/[^\p{L}\p{N}\s]+/gu, "");
  if(verbose) { console.log('s => ' + search); }

  // 2. multiple to one space, add optional unicode marks
  search = search.replace(/\s+/gu, " ").replace(/.{0}/gu, '\\p{M}*');

  // 3. diacritic-character variants, add variable space
  ['[اأإآ]','[وؤ]','[يئ]','\\s+'].forEach((v) => {
    search = search.replace(new RegExp(v, "gu"), v);
  });
  
  if(verbose) { console.log('p => ' + search); }
  let p = new RegExp(search, 'gui'); // i-flag if latin chars
  return text.replace(p,'<span class="highlighted">$&</span>');
}

// test
s = 'والشم'; txt = 'اَلْيَوْمُ جَمِيلٌ وَالشَّمْسُ';
console.log(highlightArabic(s, txt, true));

s = 'قل اعوذ'; txt = 'قُلْ أَعُوذُ بِرَبِّ النَّاسِ'
console.log(highlightArabic(s, txt, true));



Note that I used .{0} to add \p{M}* between all characters. If search often contains latin numbers and letters, you could target only the arabic chracters by (?=[ء-ي٠-٩])|(?<=[ء-ي٠-٩]).
Reference

How to find and remove first/starting string from an Arabic string having diacritics but maintaining the original diacritics of remaining string (this answer was helpful)
Search Arabic word with accent marks/diacritics
Regex match Arabic keyword
Regular Expression Arabic characters and numbers only


Thankyou man, really appreciate the time and effort you put in for the problem. will in sha' Allah try the solution and check it thoroughly.
may Allah guide you!

To achieve your desired result of wrapping the matched word with HTML  tags while ignoring certain characters (like the period in this case), you can modify your regular expression pattern to use a negative lookahead assertion. Here's how you can do it:
const searchText = 'thing';
const result = 'some th.in.g';
// Escape special characters in the search text
const escapedSearchText = searchText.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, 
'\\$&');

// Construct the regular expression pattern with negative lookahead
const regex = new RegExp(`\\b${escapedSearchText.replace(/\./g, '\\.')} 
(?!\\.)\\b`, 'gi');

// Replace the matched word with HTML span tags
const finalText = result.replace(regex, '<span class="highlighted">$& 
</span>');

console.log(finalText);

